# A question about printing numbers in a specific format in C

Tags: c, syntax, formatting

C-Programming Question:

> We want to get a positive integer number in seconds and print it with
>   format HH:MM:SS.

For example if we get 3600, we must print 01:00:00. or 4201 -> 01:10:01 (The preceding 0s must be printed). I know how to get the hour and minute and second numbers but my problem is with the output format.

Note: We can't use any time related function (for example time.h functions, structs and etc.) and also we cannot use if-statement (in order to check whether the hour or minute or second number is less than 10 or not). How can we do this? Is it possible?

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks. Is there any site that has complete list of % usages in C output?

Comment: @user3121023. No I don't have Linux and that is because I want a full list on internet. Anyway, if you submit your answer, I can accept it as the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: @user3121023. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't your textbook explain how to use `printf()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We want to get a positive integer number in seconds and print it with format HH:MM:SS.
>
> I know how to get the hour and minute and second numbers but my problem is with the output format.

Use `"%02d"` [@user3121023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52635914/a-question-about-printing-numbers-in-a-specific-format-in-c#comment92205078_52635914).

`"2"` is the *minimum* text width.
`"0"`  causes padding to use `'0'` to make up the minimum width.

```
printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
```

---

More interesting is how to print all `int total`.  That has sign issues with breaking that into `hour, minute, second` and range issues for `hour`.

`".2"` is the *minimum* digits width.  This should be used with `hour` to insure -7 is printed as "-07" and not "-7".

```
#define SECS_PER_MIN 60
#define MINS_PER_HOUR 60

// Print time, valid for all `int`
void print_hms(int total /* total seconds */) {
  int sec =  total%SECS_PER_MIN;
  total /= SECS_PER_MIN;
  int min =  total%MINS_PER_HOUR;
  total /= MINS_PER_HOUR;
  int hour = total;

  // use abs() to print negative, `min,sec` without a sign
  printf("%0.2d:%02d:%02d", hour, abs(min), abs(sec));
}
```

Sample

```
print_hms(0);
print_hms(3600 + 23*60 + 45);
print_hms(24*3600);
print_hms(-7*3600);
print_hms(INT_MIN);

00:00:00
01:23:45
24:00:00
-07:00:00
-596523:14:08
```